# How to set up Keras LSTM for time series forecasting?

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a single training batch of 600 sequential points (x(t), y(t)) with x(t) being a 25 dimensional vector and y(t) being my target (1 dim). I would like to train an LSTM to predict how the series would continue given a few additional x(t) [t> 600]. I tried the following model:

```
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (600,25), batch_size = 1, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences = True)) 
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20 ,verbose=2) prediction

    prediction = model.predict(testX, batch_size = 1)
```

Fitting works fine, but I keep getting the following error at the prediction step:

```
    Error when checking : expected lstm_46_input to have shape (1, 600, 25) but got array with shape (1, 10, 25)
```

What am I missing?

Here are my shapes:

```
    trainX.shape = (1,600,25)
    trainY.shape = (1,600,1)
    testX.shape = (1,10,25)
```

Answer (score 5):

According to Keras documentation input of LSTM (or any RNN) layers should be of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)` where your input shape is

> trainX.shape = (1,600,25)

So it means for training you are passing only one data with 600 timesteps and 25 features per timestep. But I got a feeling that you actually have **600 training data** each having **25 timesteps** and **1 feature per timestep**. I guess your input shape (trainX) should be `600 x 25 x 1`. Train target (trainY) should be  `600 x 1` If my assumption is right then your test data should be of shape `10 x 25 x 1`. First LSTM layer should be written as

```
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (25,1), batch_size = 1, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences = False))
```

Comment: also if the y shape is correct, he probably needs a `TimeDistributed(Dense(1))` as he has an output per timestep.

Comment: for 2D input, inputs is (batch_size, input_size), input_shape = (25,1) means batch_size=25, not timesteps.

Answer (score 2):

If your training data is in fact (1,600,25) what this means is you are unrolling the LSTM feedback 600 times. The first input has an impact on the 600th input.  If this is what you want, you can use the Keras function "pad_sequences" to add append zeros to the test matrix so it has the shape (1,600,25).  The network should predict zeros and you will need to add 590 zeros to your testY.

If you only want say 10 previous timesteps to affect your current Y prediction, then you will want to turn your trainX into shape (590,10,25).  The input line will be something like:

```
model.add(LSTM(n_hid, stateful=True, return_sequences=False, batch_input_shape=(1,nTS,x_train.shape[2])))
```

The processing to get it in the form you want could be something like this:

```
def formatTS(XX, yy, window_length):
x_train = np.zeros((XX.shape[0]-window_length,window_length,XX.shape[1]))
for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    x_train[i] = XX[i:i+window_length,:]
y_train = yy[window_length:]
return x_train, y_train
```

Then your testing will work just fine since it is already in the shape (1,10,25).